# How to render a 3D object using GLView in Expo?

Tags: react-native, 3d, expo

I have tried this example from Expo's official website but it doesnt display a 3D object. Just two squares that do not move at all

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view/

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <GLView style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} onContextCreate={onContextCreate} />
    </View>
  );
}

function onContextCreate(gl) {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);

  // Create vertex shader (shape & position)
  const vert = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(
    vert,
    `
    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      gl_PointSize = 150.0;
    }
  `
  );
  gl.compileShader(vert);

  // Create fragment shader (color)
  const frag = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(
    frag,
    `
    void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
  `
  );
  gl.compileShader(frag);

  // Link together into a program
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vert);
  gl.attachShader(program, frag);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);

  gl.flush();
  gl.endFrameEXP();
}
```

I want to be able to display a 3D object (possibly a dish/food) using Expo.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of 3d cube moving around on a screen and rotating https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/apps/native-component-list/src/screens/GL/GLSnapshotsScreen.tsx
There are also few more examples in that directory.

`expo-gl` is implementation of WebGL standard, so if you you are looking for information how to do something, I suggest googling how to do that in WebGL. Anything specific to `expo-gl` you need to know is that onContextCreate and creating GLView, after you have gl object, this is pure WebGL.